# one-to-one or one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a stock control application.
I have a table called "equipment_type" that stores a general
description of a piece of equipment. This could be for instance: Canon
60D DSLR camera.
I also have an table called "equipment" that stores all the equipment
we have with their serial numbers. There may be many Canon 60Ds and
they should refer to the "equipment_type" table for their description.
Is this a one-to-one association, because they have only one
description.
Or is this a one-to-many, because one "equipment_type" is related to
many "equipment"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-to-many relationship. That is one `equipment_type` for many `equipment`. In rails this would be defined:

```
class Equipment
  belongs_to :equipment_type
end

class EquipmentType
  has_many :equipment
end
```

Note: Rails should recognize that `equipment` is both singular and plural, so using something like `equipments` is incorrect. You can test this in the console using `"equipment".pluralize` and `"equipment".singularize`.